# Removing specific phrases from a long string (replace function + regex?) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, string, replace

I'm currently learning Angular I'm having an issue with transforming a certain long string.

So, this is my div with a lot of lines, generated by ng-repeat:

http://pastebin.com/raw/bJqqUvpY

Yeah, it's pretty nasty, I know. What i want to do is to remove all the ng attributes and other stuff that I don't need from that string, because I'm going to pass this data to PHP via ajax.

Here's what I tried to do (angular):

```
    $scope.updateHtml = function() {    
    var testVal = angular.element('#sendHtml').val();
        testVal = testVal.replace(/ng-class="{'selected':selection.indexOf($index) != -1}"/g,"");
    $scope.sendHtml.html = testVal;
};
```

But it doesn't work. Perhaps it's because of the quotation marks inside of the phrase, or is it?

This, for instance, works with a replacement of a single letter:

```
$scope.updateHtml = function() {
     var testVal = angular.element('#sendHtml').val();
     testVal = 'abcabcabc';
    testVal = testVal.replace(/b/g,"");
    $scope.sendHtml.html = testVal;
};
```

Then `$scope.sendHtml.html` is equal to `'acacac'` like it should.
Could this be solved with another kind of RegEx?

Comment: The `$` is a special regex char, it  must be escaped. Dot, `(`, and `)` should be escaped, too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape dot `.`, parenthesis `()`, and dollar `$` signs.

`testVal = testVal.replace(/ng-class="{'selected':selection\.indexOf\(\$index\) != -1}"/g,"");`

Demo: http://regexr.com/3enmj

On the website you can examine all characters that should be escaped, by opening menu *Reference* - *Escaped Characters*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove all the ng-* directives as well as the html comments generated you can try [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/lzaeg1/1).

```
\sng-[a-z]*="(.*?)"|(<!--(.*?)-->)
```

You remove a whitespace `\s` followed by `ng-` and any number of characters `[a-z]*` followed by double quotes and what's inside "(.*?)" as well as the html comments `<!--(.*?)-->` and what's inside.

Can probably be improved but it works for cleaning your input.